# java jni store class instance for later reuse

Tags: java, class, java-native-interface, instance

my java classes that mirror C++ classes contain a field
that holds the C++ pointer to the C++ instance
this part works as normal as many other wrappers

What I want to do is the other way round as well

I want to be able to store the java instance in the C++ class's userdata field

when the c++ library I'm wrapping returns a c++ class instance I want to be able
to take the userdata and convert it back into the java class instance that holds
the that pointer, i do NOT want to recreate a new java object with the pointer but
reuse the original class instance...

to aid this explanation I'll detail an example life cycle

a new java object is created
the java object constructor calls a native function with "this"
it creates a C++ object that the java object is mirroring
the java "this" reference is stored in the C++ object "userData" field

when another C++ function returns a c++ pointer, this pointer is used
to retrieve the userData containing the reference to the java instance
that encapsulates it

the java instance of the original object is returned to java...

where I have passed the java value to this to C++ and casted it to a long
printf always shows the same value for different instances!!

Answer (score 0):

when another C++ function returns a c++ pointer, this pointer is used to retrieve the userData containing the reference to the java instance that encapsulates it

Comment: when another C++ function returns a c++ pointer, this pointer is used to retrieve the userData containing the reference to the java instance that encapsulates it

Comment: sorry that doesn't make sense can you reword your answer, specifically how can I store a reference (in c++) to a specific java class *instance* and later (in java) recreate that object